# jQuery function to check classes between two divs?

Tags: jquery

I've got a page with two sets of `div` like so

```
<div id="set1">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
.....
<div class="n"></div>
</div>

<div id="set2">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
.....
<div class="n"></div>
</div>
```

"set2" is hidden on page load but each div needs to appear when the corresponding div in "set1" is clicked. For example, when "div#set1.1" is clicked, "div#set2.1" will show up. How can I do this with jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var set2 = $('#set2');

$('#set1 > div').click(function(){
    set2.find('.' + this.className).show();
});
```

We first cache `#set2` for performance reasons, then attach a click event handler to each of the child `div` of `#set1`, which when clicked, will cause the corresponding `div` with the same class in `#set2` to appear. See http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/xCEVH/1/ for a simple demo.

However, class names starting with numbers are not valid in HTML. I've taken the liberty of correcting that mistake in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#set1 .1').click(function(event){
    $('#set2 .1').show();
})
```

This would add the feature. Repeat that for the other divs or use for-loops to automate this.

Comment: thanks. if you noticed, my last div was "n", which meant i'm not sure how many there will be in all. how can i loop this function to check the classes that match between the two ids?

Comment: Sry, I have not enough time, to provide this code right now. I just noticed, that it would work without a for-loop. I will edit my answer to provide a better solution when I'm at home, if nobody else could answer your question until then ;)

Answer (score 0):

If parent div is hidden you won't be able to show any if its children.
With jQuery you can do something like [this](http://jsbin.com/eleci3/2/edit):

hide all children of set2

```
#set2 div{
   display:none;
}
```

and then when item is clicked - show all items of that class.

```
$("#set1 div").click(function(){
   $('.'+ this.className).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#set1').bind('click',function() {

    $('#2.'+$(this).attr('id').substring(2)).show();

    });
```